# get element id for animate jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, getelementbyid

I have a sprite image than when mouseenter/mouseleave occurs over it, the background position  changes.This is working so far although there is probably a more efficient way of doing it. However I have several images I need to do this with and am trying to find a way to feed the id of the image into the jQuery rather than duplicate code. 
The HTML:

```
<div class='featSmallBox' id='featSmallImg2'>
</div>
```

The image source is placed using CSS.
This is what I have so far for the jQuery.

```
 $("#featSmallImg2").mouseenter(function(){
                    $(this).animate({
                   backgroundPositionX:"100%"
                     });
                   });

 $("#featSmallImg2").mouseleave(function(){
                    $(this).animate({
                   backgroundPositionX:"0%"
                     });
                    });
```

Ideally I need to feed in the id of what is being mouseentered dynamically, but everything I've tried doesn't seem to work. 
Apologies if this makes little to no sense. I'm new to both jQuery and this site.

Comment: I think your code is having a typo! isn't it? `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` are not closed :) Is it your actual code?

Comment: @DhavalMarthak his code is correct. Both events are closed on line 4 and 8 respectively!

Comment: @DhavalMarthak you were right! just forgot to put them in on here for some reason

Comment: No problem, it happens.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the jQuery code is the same for all divs containing the sprites, try changing `$("#featSmallImg2")` in your jQuery to `$(".featSmallBox")`. This way, all your divs with the class `.featSmallBox` will have this feature.

Comment: This solution worked straight away! However later on i'll be sliding text over the image( again the text is different for each image) also and when I do so, it slides text for all images not just the one being hovered. I shoulda put that up really..

Comment: @Shamrockonov I would suggest then that you mark my answer as correct (by clicking the hollow tick to the left of the answer) to close this question, and then post a new question detailing how you want the sliding text to work, as it would get a bit messy if you'd start editing the current question (and all the answers would be made irrelevant). You can also send me a PM if you wish to discuss this further before or instead of posting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Check with **[event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)**

```
$( "body" ).mouseenter(function( event ) {
   console.log( "mouseentered id: " + event.target.id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div[id^='featSmallImg']").mouseenter(function(){
                    $(this).animate({
                   backgroundPositionX:"100%"
                     });
                   });

$("div[id^='featSmallImg']").mouseleave(function(){
                    $(this).animate({
                   backgroundPositionX:"0%"
                     });
                    });
```

Try this code. Event will be called for all div's whose id starts with 'featSmallImg'

Comment: Will only be valid if background position after animating should be same for all the divisions.